# Issue creating read-only user in PostgreSQL that results in user with greater permission with public schema

Tags: postgresql

I'm learning PostgreSQL and now I'm trying to create a read-only user.

```
CREATE USER user WITH PASSWORD 'password';
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE my-database TO user;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public to user;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public to user;
```

However, I'm having issues using the `public schema` which has permissions to CREATE databases and others.

I don't want to affect other users or modify the public schema.
What would be the best way to GRANT FULL ONLY READ ACCESS?

Thanks from a newbie!

Comment: To create a database the user needs the `CREATEDB` privilege or be a superuser. Your `user` role has neither. Please verify your issue and add details to your question of what your problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot solve this problem without modifying the `public` schema. You will have to

```
REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
```

Comment: Thanks, @Laurenz Albe
So what would be the best way to create a read-only user in your experience?

Comment: Grant `SELECT` permissions on all tables and views and `USAGE` on all schemas, and make sure that no write permissions are granted to `PUBLIC`.

Comment: Thanks again, @Laurenz Albe
Excuse my ignorance, but this is not going to affect other users or the functionality of my app, no?

Comment: It may, if the application tries to create objects in `public`. If it doesn't, it should be no problem. Test it!